# Fixing my Scala Intellij project when loading it from an existing project in sbt and dependencies download fails

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Oftentimes I have troubles with sbt downloading its dependencies when behind a corporate firewall when trying to `"Load a project from existing sources" -> sbt`. It eventually times out and leaves my project in the following state:

there is some problem when 
[image]

I can at this point download all my dependencies through the sbt-terminal tool (or the command-line) but Intellij will still keep this "view", instead of correctly showing me the diverse folders the project contains (like `src/`, `test/`, etc).

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Does the regular "refresh" button on the sbt tool window not work? In that case importing the project again should do the trick.
For reference: Does this issue seem related? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9856

Answer (score 0):

I also have had this problem multiple times. I usually close IntelliJ, clean its repository `rm -rf .idea/`, and then open the project folder (instead of importing it). It's always done the job for me.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference here.